# CPU registers width, and memory addressing (32-bit or 64-bit)

Tags: hardware, cpu

I have processor Intel Xeon CPU E3-1230 with 4 cores:

This is 64-bit processor which means that memory addresses are 64-bit wide, however the spec for this CPU at http://ark.intel.com/products/75054/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E3-1230-v3-8M-Cache-3_30-GHz says that the max RAM size is 32G.

Besides why does address size reported by /proc/cpuinfo differ?

```
% grep ^address /proc/cpuinfo | uniq
address sizes   : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
% uname -sr
% Linux 3.16.2-201.fc20.x86_64
%
```

**UPDATE**
x86_64 or Intel-64 are said to be extensions to the IA-32 architecture. Does it mean that the cpu is still 32-bit with 64-bit extensions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does literature really say that the memory addresses are 64-bit wide? Because I can only recall it talking about registers being able to hold 64 bits of data. Anyway the max RAM and address size is basically a "hardware implementation" aspect. AFAIK noone has yet implemented full 64bit of address size, as it has little practical use so far and there are drawbacks to increasing the address size (performance decreases)

Comment: @UnholySheep, wiki http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing says that memory addressing is 64-bit. So whatever /proc/cpuinfo reports is the actual addressing size on the platform?

Comment: Well, I would never, ever consider wikipedia to be reliable literature, however even that article has a section labeled "Limitations of practical processors". so yes, basically /proc/cpuinfo reports the actual values.

Comment: @UnholySheep, the datasheet available at http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/xeon/xeon-e3-1200v3-vol-1-datasheet.html says about 64-bit wide channels in the section "2.1 System memory interface", so I guess it does mean that the memory addresses are 64-bit long.

Comment: No, you are misunderstanding the terms. 64-bit wide channels are unrelated to the CPU (they are specific to the RAM) and have existed for quite some time. In fact ECC RAM often has 72-bit wide channels. This is just for data transfer between RAM and CPU and is not affected by memory address size

Comment: Processors often bring out fewer physical address lines than they might support internally for addressing. In the case of current Intel CPUs, they don't actually bring out raw physical address lines for interface to RAM, rather they integrate a DRAM controller so that the various lines used to interface to DDR are brought out of the package. These physical lines to DDR RAM are not simply physical address lines - there's CAS, RAS, memory address lines which are multiplexed (so there's only 16 of them per bank). This CPU package supports up to 4 8GB DIMMs for a total of 32GB DDR RAM.

Comment: Thanks for comments. How is the virtual memory size calculated given the size of physical RAM. i.e. is there any specific formula for this? On my machine with Xeon E3 /proc/cpuinfo reports 48 bits for virtual address size, yielding 2^48 max virt memory available. How does this number correspond to 32G max available physical memory?

Comment: 48bit virtual memory includes both main[physical ddr] memory and swap space.[yes swap is physical storage in some low level sense but it is only emulating RAM thus virtual]  So the memory controller can handle some set of real RAM addresses due to physical construction, but all userspace programs will see 2^48 bytes. Allowing more portable software and flex in physical design. Long ago (1970s-80s) there was no virtual memory space, no swap, software could not be executed at all if it did not fit in physical RAM.  To make use of increases in physical address space required rewrite and compile.

Comment: Current software for full operating systems(not microcontrollers) is written for its own private memory space that starts at 0 and goes to 2^48, and the OS translates these into physical ram addresses as needed, in fixed blocks called pages. Pages are scattered around RAM and disk; when a disk page is needed it is "swapped" with least used RAM page. Unused virtual addresses are not given any real address. Before virtual memory, user apps required a fixed *continuous* block of physical RAM, any 'swapping' would just be the app doing traditional disk writes to clear some of its space for reuse.

Comment: The 48bit software convention(256TiB)  and 52bit amd64 architecture limit(The standard, not the physical implementations.) were a legacy design choice by AMD. It comes from a simple one level extension of the old 32bit PAE page table system and would be very difficult to rejigger into using the full 64bit space without some breaking changes to backward compatibility. 32b PAE used 40b but aligned to 64b, going beyond 64b is unneeded and costly.  By the time 2^52(or even 2^48) becomes a real limit, all of the tech will have moved on to some new design standard.

Answer (score 3):

x86-64 currently only supports 48 bits of virtual address. The more significant bits must be a sign extension of the most significant valid/variable bit (the 48th), i.e., those bits are the same as the 48th bit. This is a consequence of the hierarchical page table format only supporting four levels. (A future extension could add another level, adding nine more bits to the virtual address, or provide another way of extending the size of a valid virtual address.)

*Physical* addresses are limited at several points. First, the page table entries define which bits are used to provide an address translation.  x86-64 has some reserved bits available in page table entries, so this limit can be increased in the future without having to use contortions like requiring the use of 2MiB (or larger) pages to provide larger physical addresses. (Since large pages would have the less significant physical address bits be zero by definition — pages being naturally aligned —, these can be reclaimed to extend the physical address range. This was done for 4 MiB pages for 32-bit x86.) This limit is enforced by the MMU (TLB and page table walker). This is presumably the 39-bit address limit reported under /proc/cpuinfo.

Another constraint is support in cache tags. This constrains the amount of *cacheable* memory. Physical addresses can also be used for I/O devices and (theoretically) for uncacheable memory.

Finally, the size of ordinary physical memory (excluding I/O devices) is limited by the memory controllers (and their physical interface to DRAM). This constraint would typically be the same as the cache tag constraint (since uncacheable main memory is not generally considered very useful), though with a non-power-of-two number of memory channels it might be less than the cache tag constraint (e.g., with three memory channels each channel might support 8GiB, totaling 24GiB while the cache tags, being limited to full bits, support 32GiB). This is the 32 GiB constraint listed on the linked Intel ARK page.

---

Concerning x86-64 being an extension of IA-32, this means that 32-bit code will run (correctly) on an x86-64 implementation. (See [Wikipedia's x86-64 operating modes table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#Operating_modes) for a quick overview.)

Comment: thank you for you comment. What is the limiting factor for the actual size of virtual memory in the system? I guess it is not only amount of the physical RAM? In other words, even though x86_64 supports 2^48 bytes of the virtual memory, this is more a theoretical number, isn't it ?

Comment: @Mark The size of the virtual memory address space (for flat addressing, ignoring segments and other complicating factors) is limited first by the size of register used for addressing (64 bits in x86-64) and second (for ISAs with hardware TLB fill like x86 and ARM) by the nature of the page table. x86 uses a hierarchical page table where the base of the table points to a page of pointers (and metadata such as permissions) each of which points to another page of pointers, etc. Since each entry is 8b and the page size is 4KiB, each level has 512 entries, indexed with 9 virt. addr. bits. ...

Comment: With four levels each covering 9 bits and the 12 bits that are the offset within the 4KiB page, the page table can handle 48 bits of virtual address space (9+9+9+9+12). Adding a level would add 9 more bits. In ISAs without hardware TLB fill, the size of the virtual address space can vary more freely, mainly being a design decision concerning TLB tags and compatibility with software for previous implementations. Anyway, yes, the size of the virtual memory address space is somewhat arbitrary.